# Google Cloud SQL Exports Permissions

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-sql, google-cloud-iam

We've been running a daily automated full database exports from Google Cloud SQL to Google Cloud Storage (across projects) using Cloud Functions to trigger the export. (See this [article](https://medium.com/@kennethteh90/how-to-schedule-daily-cloud-sql-export-to-google-cloud-storage-4c1bd360af06))

Starting 4 days ago, we're getting a 403 error with the logs showing: "The service account does not have the required permissions for the bucket."

We haven't made any permissions changes and running:
`gsutil acl get [BUCKET]`
still shows that our Google Cloud SA has the role "WRITER" as we'd expect.

From our perspective, it seems like we've randomly lost permissions for this workflow. Does anyone have any suggestions on how to debug this and get this workflow working again?

Edit: This seems like a bug that was introduced recently, https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/166478544

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are correct, it seems that this is, indeed, a bug that seems to be affecting the situation. Regarding your question in the public issue that you linked, it seems that it's related indeed, to the permissions in a bucket level. Considering the fact that the bug is affecting you at a bucket level, makes more sense to use permission within this level, than modifying the whole roles from your IAM. For you to modify the permissions in a bucket level, you can follow the instructions indicated [here](https://docs.cloudera.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.6.5/bk_cloud-data-access/content/edit-bucket-permissions.html).

Or, just follow the below steps.

1. In the Google Cloud Platform web console, navigate to Storage Browser.
2. Find the bucket for which you want to edit permissions.
3. Click the three dots and select Edit bucket permissions.
4. In the Permissions tab set the bucket-level permissions.
5. Click on Add members and enter the service account that you want to use to access the bucket.
6. Under Roles, select Storage Object Admin or another role that allows accessing the bucket. The ones associated to `storage.buckets.get` are available [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/iam-roles).
7. Click `Add`, once you are done.

Anyway, I would recommend you to follow the workaround and wait for updates in the [public issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/166478544), until it's fixed. However, keep in mind that as the [official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/uniform-bucket-level-access) indicates, bucket level access is actually recommended.